# Comparing and Matching two data frames and storing the values in a third data frame

Tags: r

Hi sorry if the title is a bit vague, i will try to explain my problem.

I currently have two dataframes and would like to compare values in the two.

For an example say the two are exactly the same.

`df1<- data.frame("a" = c(1,2,3,4), "b" = c(123,41,51,25), "c" = c("apple", "pear","banana","peach"))`

`df2<- data.frame("a" = c(1,2,3,4), "b" = c(123,41,51,25), "c" = c("apple", "pear","banana","peach"))`

I would like the to make the third dataframe to have the same column names a,b,c but have 0, 1 for if the rows match. to look something like

`df3 <- data.frame("a" = c(1,1,1,1), "b" = c(1,1,1,1), "c", c(1,1,1,1))`

so far I have tried

`for (i in colname(df1)){ df3$1 = ifelse(df1[[i]]==df2[[2]],1, 0)}`

but it doesn't seem to be working. I think my issue is using `df3$i` but I also tried `df3[[i]]` as well. Ideally i would like this to work on larger dataframes as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your df1 and df2 are the same i.e. `all.equal(df1, df2)#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: Yeah, i was just using that as an example, ideally it would give all 1's in df3 if they are the same and 0 if not

Answer (score 1):

If we need to create a binary dataset, just do `==` and coerce the logical to binary with (`+`).  The TRUE/FALSE is otherwise 1/0

```
+(df1 == df2)
```

If we want to do the same with the `for` loop (`ifelse` is not really required)

```
for(i in seq_along(df1)) df3[[i]] <- ifelse(df1[[i]] == df2[[i]], 1, 0)
```

Comment: hmm thanks, i think i kind of understand what you're saying. is it possible to do something like this with the code i currently have?

Comment: @arkun Great, this is similar to what i was looking for. if i wanted to keep the column names, should i establish that before my for loop?

Comment: @KoalaKeeper You can either loop over the sequence or column names as long as the column names are the same in both datasets

Comment: @arkun It worked wonderfully. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an option would be:

```
#Code
df3 <- data.frame(df1==df2)
df3 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df3,as.numeric))
```

Output:

```
  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1
3 1 1 1
4 1 1 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I was thinking of something like this but i was worried that since my datafiles would be upwards of MB to GB the runtime would be too long.

Comment: It depends sometimes `base R` can have some speed :)